# Android : Best way to display numbers in a grid and an android plot at the bottom of the grid

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am working on my first android app and i am trying to to get something like the  following layout to display

[image]

The first section has 3 columns and all of them will continuously display numbers

The next section is a horizontal androidplot graph which continuously displays 2 of the three numbers

I tried playing with gridlayout and also looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447234/android-creating-two-columns-in-a-linearlayout) but couldn't get the desired layout to show up

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks ,

Comment: added a screenshot on my answer down there, check it out to see if its adjust to your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you like it, have fun:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="36"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:background="@color/gray_bg"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="51"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="40"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:background="@color/gray_bg"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="AndroidPlot"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: it works perfectly...only thing is that  increasing the android:textSize="48sp" does not increase the font size of the numbers . I want the numbers to consume about 35-40% of the screen space(either on a tablet or phone) and the font size should adjust accordingly ...any ideas?

Comment: the 3 Textviews here are instructed to wrap the content just increase the textSize parameter on both 3 and they will expand downwards, try it out :), if not I can modify it for you...

Comment: turns out i was setting the textsize in the java code which overrode the xml values...so it works perfectly now...thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="2" />

        <TextView
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="lorem ipsum" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: damned, next time i'm faster... :)