# Position an element below a multiline EditText

Tags: android, layout

I have a list of data displayed as  , one below the other:
name     James
phone    032-432-4556
street   line 1
         line 2
         etc.
email    me@my.com

The most logical (I guess) is to position the email  below the street , as the edittext is variabel in length and left align it with previous textviews. Whichever combination of layout params I've tried, "Email" remains immediatly below the "street" label. Even the margin is not respected. Who knows the correct combination of layout params and referred to items?

This is my layout and below it the screen as it shows:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".DisplayContact" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/oneContact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTextName"
        .............
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        .............
    </EditText>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTextPhone"
        .............
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        .............

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTextStreet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textTextPhone"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textTextName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/textTextName"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/field_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/street"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStreet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textTextStreet"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/editTextName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/editTextName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextStreet"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textTextName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/textTextName"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/field_vertical_margin"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textTextEmail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/editTextName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/editTextName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTextCity"
        .............
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCity"
        .............
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using a vertical `LinearLayout` as your root, instead of `RelativeLayout` and creating a layout as described here [Android: creating two columns in a linearlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447234/android-creating-two-columns-in-a-linearlayout)

You can also try a Table https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html.

Comment: A horizontal LinearLayout with the label and the inputfield for each line, and all these horizontal LinearLayouts together within a vertical LinearLayout. That's what works well, it adapts to growing multiline input.